# Pie Chart - format number display from .3s to .1s ( or other format )

Tags: d3.js, apache-superset

My pie chart is displaying unwanted decimal values (not present in the initial data or query). The decimal values are not accurate in this case and I need to remove them.

There are not format input available for PieCharts

Superset v0.21.1

I need to change the default .3s formatting to .1s or .2s or other formatting to fit my need.

[image]

Comment: do modify tag to 3djs instead of 3d

Comment: tag should  be d3.js

Comment: What's the type of the column you're displaying? What happens if you explicitly cast it to int?

Comment: @DavidTobiano It is already explicitly casted as an INT in the DB and in the queries that return the data it is also an INT. Its somewhere between where the query data is recuperated and converted into the 3DJS graph that the decimal is being added to the INT data

Comment: I would suggest a pull request creating that feature. You could mirror some of the other PRs with similar changes for other graphics types.